# python list all imported modules imported via *, the pythonic way

Tags: python, dynamic, import, extension-methods

Say I have a package "colorExtentions" and in my `__init__.py` I have `__all__=["red", "blue"]`. This package should be able to be extended automatically by adding modules to the directory and to the `__all__` list. Is the following acceptable or is there another "best practice" for such kind of things?

```
import colorExtentions
from colorExtentions import *

for moduleName in colorExtentions.__all__:
    colors.append(moduleName)
promptUserToChoose(colors)
```

Comment: What exactly are `red` and `blue` here? Classes? Modules?

Comment: they are modules but I call the class explicitly in my `__init__.py` with `from red import Red`.

Comment: automatically and add manually in __all__, looks like a joke.

Comment: @Psyclops If you remove the `__all__` from `colorExtentions/__init__.py`, then simply added a new module into `colorExtentions` will make it available via `from colorExtentions import *`... unless there's something more specific you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor I need to know explicitly which modules have been loaded so i can prompt the user to choose one of them for example. I need a list of sorts..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that each colour is a class, I would argue the nicer solution would be to ensure all of your colours subclass from a single class (which is good design anyway):

```
class Color:
    ...
```

Then, when you want a list of all colours, you can simply import any modules that will contain the classes, and do:

```
from colorExtentions import *

colors = Color.__subclasses__()
```

This way you end up with a list of each `Color` subclass.

Note in 2.x, you will need new-style classes (inheriting from `object`) to have the `__subclasses__()` method available.

Comment: +1 i too like that... but in my case means that for adding a new color someone should *edit* the file as opposed to *add* the file.

Comment: @Psyclops Why? They just add a module with a class in or add a class to an existing module.

Comment: I must admit, it took me a while... but THIS IS IT!! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Importing all names from modules are discouraged in the official Python documentation. See:

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import

Quote:

> When It Is Just Fine
>
> There are situations in which from module import * is just fine:
>
> - The interactive prompt. For example, from math import * makes Python
>     an amazing scientific calculator.
> - When extending a module in C with a > module in Python.
> - When the module advertises itself as from import * safe.

If you insist of using `__all__` - use some other name, like `color_list`, and extend that variable dynamically. Then import that variable:

```
import colorExtentions
from colorExtentions import color_list

colors.extends(color_list)
```

Comment: Using `__all__` is one of the ways a module "advertises itself as from import * safe".

Comment: but how can I implement an dynamic extension loader?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor yes, but it is a static list by design. I mean if you want to dynamically change `__all__` in order to be able to use `from X import *` it is a bad idea, thus makes this module not "import * safe".

Comment: @DavidFatyga Python is a dynamic language by design, there is no requirement for `__all__` to be static. As long as the behaviour is predictable and documented, then what difference does it make?

Comment: Apparently I removed the list formatting by mistake. Reverted.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor in this simple case it might be ok, but suppose I write a package that installs my malicious module into `colorExtentions` namespace. It will be imported automatically by `import *`, and in this case I can execute any code I want.